# How do I build a table view for iphone in which when you save it adds a new row instead of replacing the row?

Tags: iphone, rows, tableview

I built an app with a table view that holds frequencies and other data.  I would like to select a row, edit it, and then add the new frequencies info to a new row right below the selected row without deleted the selected row.

I'm using core data.  Everything works fine using UIBarButtonItem *saveButton method.  But it just replaces the row.  I also can use add but it puts the new row on the bottom of the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: will put the row in. You'll have to figure out how to put the right data in it in cellForRowAtIndexPath